# How to display column headers for 'ls -l' command in unix/linux?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, formatting, ls

I want to display all the column headers when I type `ls -l` command in bash shell in unix/linux

When we type `ls -ltr` on command prompt we get something like the following.

```
-r--r--r--  2   makerpm   root   1898   Jan 28 14:52   sample3
-r--r--r--  2   makerpm   root   1898   Jan 28 14:52   sample1
```

What I want is to know whether `ls` has any options to display with column headers:

```
File_Permissions  Owner Group   Size   Modified_Time  Name
-r--r--r--  2  makerpm   root   1898   Jan 28 14:52   sample3
-r--r--r--  2  makerpm   root   1898   Jan 28 14:52   sample1
```

Comment: Pipe the result to `awk`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming-related questions and questions on
*using*  Linux / Unix are [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This question would be more appropriate for [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or
[Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) (if you’re running Ubuntu). You should also clarify your description of your desired output.

Comment: could you give an example of the type of output you want?

Comment: Worth noting:  There's an extra column between `group` and `size` when you run `ls -l` in `/dev/`.  This column indicates the major number associated with each device.

Answer (score 35):

[exa](https://the.exa.website/) is a replacement/enhancement for `ls`. If you pass on the arguments `-lh` with exa, it will include a header row printing the column names like so:

```
exa -lh
```

Example output:

```
Permissions Size User     Date Modified Name
.rwx------    19 username 29 Sep 11:25  dont_cra.sh
drw-r-----     - username 29 Sep 11:26  f1
.rw-r--r--@ 811k username 29 Sep 11:25  row_count.dat
.rw-r--r--    54 username 29 Sep 11:25  some_text.txt
```

You can set up an alias in .bashrc that replaces ls with exa.

Comment: Usually, I avoid comments like 'Thank you!', 'Great!', etc. But I'm making an exception here. The 'exa' program is precisely what I was looking for. Actually, it's better than that. I strongly recommend the "stackoverflowers" to talk a look at the link. So, if the moderator allows me, thanks for the link; the program is great! :) - Upvoted!

Comment: No exa in centos. How to install it?

Comment: Note that if want `group` column, the option `-g` is needed.

Comment: Literally not what was asked

Comment: @JohnnyBigoode And yet, provides a better answer that those that address literally what was asked.

Comment: @hatfinch This response might have useful information (to some), but a response about something that wasn't asked is not an answer to the question to begin with and to then qualify that as a "better" one is just a logical fallacy. "How do manual cars work?" -> "Automatic ones are a modern replacement to manuals, so use them instead" is not a "better" answer to the asked question.

Answer (score 8):

The last answer using `sed` was slick, but unfortunately, if you have color added to your output (which most people do) it removes all color.  I would like to suggest a better way, and ironically, simpler too.

First off, my .bashrc USED to have the following:

```
# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
fi

alias ls='ls -AFhls --color --group-directories-first'
```

To be honest, you don't need the dircolors part, that is just a little extra I use, you could have something as simple as:

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

I wanted column headers too, Googled it, and wound up here.  However after I tried what the previous user suggested, with sed and realizing everything was white, and my colors have all gone away.

That's when I tried something different in my `.bashrc` file, and it worked.

Simply alias ls, echo first, then place a semi-colon, then your ls command.
My .bashrc file now has the following line.

```
alias ls='echo "Dir Size|Perms|Link Count|Owner|Group|Size|Mod. Time|Name"; ls -AFhls --color --group-directories-first'
```

When doing it this way, utilizing echo instead of sed, all colors continue to work.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this is specific to my terminal's output but, this worked for me.

[image]

And this is the output it yields. As you can see, it preserves color using this method. Just be sure to keep the `${1}` variable in double quotes so files and directories with spaces in the name won't cause an error.

[image]

Here is the code so you can copy and paste for testing.

```
long_ls() {

local VAR="Permissions|Owner|Group|Size|Modified|Name"

if [ ! "${1}" ]; then
   echo -e "$VAR" | column -t -s"|" && ls -l
else
   echo -e "$VAR" | column -t -s"|" && ls -l "${1}"
fi

}

alias lls=$"long_ls ${1}"
```

Comment: How do I execute this? Is this inside a script file somewhere? Are these settings in your custom terminal?

Comment: this shell is kept in /bin folder and given 777 permission